# Consume AMF methods without Flash

Tags: php, perl, amfphp

I have to call an existing AMF Method in a PHP (or Perl) Script and read its results.

Is it possible to use amfphp to invoke it instead of serving AMFs? or use other tool? Am I trapped to use Flash?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [AMF::Perl](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?AMF%3A%3APerl) interface.

Answer (score 0):

If you can consider python: pyamf have an amf client interface:
http://www.pyamf.org/tutorials/general/client.html

Answer (score 0):

There's also an [AMF client in PHP](http://lab.publicreative.com/2009/03/amf-command-line-utility/) that works rather nicely as a command-line tool.